# Sort in descending order, using hive table in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Hive table with account numbers and most recent updated dates.  Not every account is updated each day, so I can't simply select all records from a certain day.  I need to group by account number and then sort in descending order to take the most recent 2 days for each account.  My script so far:

```
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import sqlContext.implicits._
val df1 = sqlContext.sql("FROM mydb.mytable SELECT account_num, last_updated")
val DFGrouped = df1.groupBy("account_num").orderBy(desc("data_dt"))
```

I'm getting error on the orderBy:

```
value orderBy is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData
```

Any idea on what I should be doing here?

Comment: It looks like you want to order the elements within the sub-groups.  If so, you might try something like: `groupBy(...).map(_.orderBy(...))`

Comment: @jwh It won't work. `groupBy` is just logical operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping will not work here because this is a form of the [top N by group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22833503/622495) problem.

You need to use [Spark SQL window functions](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html), in particular, rank() with partition by account ID and order by date descending, followed by selecting the rows with rank <= 2.